# Compare two arrays of objects; If second object contains the same key/value as the first return the second's, if not add key/value from the first

Tags: javascript

Consider the following: We have two arrays, each with an object.

```
let users: [
  {
    "id": "some#"
    "name": "some name",
    "data": "somedata"
  }
],


let products: [
    {
      "product": "some#"
      "name": "abc",
    },
]
```

Essentially compare both objects, if the second object has the same property as the first, keep the second prop and value if not add the prop/value from the first.

So the output is :

```
{
  "id": "some#",
  "name": "abc",
  "data": "somedata"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!(users[0].name === products[0].name)) {
product[0].data = users[0].data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code below, for the data you have given, you can have that output you are looking for:

```js
let users = [
  {
    id: "some#",
    name: "some name",
    data: "somedata"
  }
];

let products = [
  {
    product: "some#",
    name: "abc"
  }
];

for (key in users[0]) {
  if (products[0][key]) {
    users[0][key] = products[0][key];
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
console.log(users);
```